# The Gauß map of a minimal surface: is it holomorphic or antiholomorphic?

Tags: differential-geometry, definition, riemannian-geometry, minimal-surfaces

I'm reading *A survey on classical minimal surface theory*, by William H. Meeks and Joaquín Pérez. In the early beginning, they start giving eight definitions of minimal surfaces. The last of them is

> **Definition 2.1.8** A surface $M\subset \Bbb R^3$ is *minimal* if and only if its stereographically projected Gauß map $g:M\to \Bbb{C}\cup \{\infty\}$ is meromorphic with respect to the underlying Riemann surface structure.

The authors try to justify this definition as follows: a previous definition of minimal surfaces says that a surface $M\subset \Bbb R^3$ is minimal if it has indentically zero mean curvature. So, if $N:M\to \Bbb S^2\subset \Bbb R^3$ is the usual Gauß map, we know that $-dN_p:T_pM\to T_p\Bbb S^2\cong T_pM$ is a linear symmetric operator $\forall p\in M$ and, therefore, choosing an orthonormal basis for $T_pM$,
$$-dN_p=\begin{pmatrix} a&b\\b&c\end{pmatrix},$$
a symmetric matrix. Since $$H=\text{arithmetic average of principal curvatures} = \frac{1}{2}\mathrm{trace} (-dN_p),$$ we must have $c=-a$, in order to get a *minimal* surface. Then they say that, identifying $\Bbb S^2$ with the Riemann sphere $\Bbb C\cup \{\infty\}$ together with the *Cauchy-Riemann equations*, this would show that the Gauß map $g:M\to \Bbb C\cup\{\infty\}$ must satisfy the definition above.

My doubt is: the matrix
$$-dN_p=\begin{pmatrix} a&b\\ b&-a\end{pmatrix}$$
does ***not*** satisfy Cauchy-Riemann equations. For this, it should have the form
$$\begin{pmatrix} a&-b\\ b&a\end{pmatrix}.$$

However, if I invert the orientation of $\Bbb C\cup\{\infty\}$ and "pretend" I did nothing, the matrix gets that form and Cauchy-Riemann equations are indeed satisfied.

Furthermore, other sources (like this [Handbook of Differential Geometry](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=U2BIz8NNksYC&pg=PA228&lpg=PA228&dq=minimal%20surfaces%20gauss%20map%20anti%20holomorphic&source=bl&ots=OH1hQg8YUy&sig=i4cMRjaG4V2u4vV-AYlTQn1CZOc&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwihvozlmu7ZAhWHQZAKHe6jCPEQ6AEIbjAJ#v=onepage&q=minimal%20surfaces%20gauss%20map%20anti%20holomorphic&f=false)) says in page 228 that such Gauß maps of minimal surfaces are indeed ***anti***-holomorphic.

Which definition is correct?