# Gauss map is conformal for minimal surfaces.

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry, surfaces, riemann-surfaces, minimal-surfaces

My problem is:

Prove that the Gauss map of a minimal surface $S$ in the Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^3$ is conformal.

My intuition tells me that this is true but I don't know how to attack the problem. I've looked at the differential of Gauss map but no ideea, also i don't know how to use the fact that $S$ is minimal.

EDIT: By [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2692157/the-gau%C3%9F-map-of-a-minimal-surface-is-it-holomorphic-or-antiholomorphic)  question I know that the gauss map is anti-holomorphic. Thus my question becomes, is any anti-holomorphic function a conformal function? I know that this is true for holomorphic functions.

Comment: Holomorphic maps and antiholomorphic maps between surfaces are weakly conformal.  You need to make sure $df$ is never zero.

Comment: @user10354138 weakly conformal? I don't know the term. For me, conformal map is just angle-preserving transformation.

Comment: Conformal at a point $p$ means the derivative $df(p)$ is invertible and preserves orthogonality (equivalently, preserves angles).  Weakly conformal means conformal or $df(p)=0$.  You need weakly conformal to deal with the cases such as $z\mapsto z^2$ on $\mathbb{C}$ which is clearly holomorphic, but isn't conformal at $0$.

Comment: @user10354138 Got you! Can you point me to a good ref for this elementary complex analysis?

Comment: Holomorphic functions are analytic, the complex conjugate of an anti-holomorphic function is holomorphic. If $f$ is analytic then (weak) conformality of $f(z)$ or $\bar{f(z)}$ is easy to see

Answer (score 1):

When $N: S\rightarrow \mathbb{S}^2$ is unit out normal, then assume
that $S$ is a minimal surface whose principal curvatures are $k,\
-k$ at a point $p$. Hence $dN : T_pS\rightarrow
T_{N(p)}\mathbb{S}^2$ is a linear map, i.e. $dN $ is a diagonal
matrix $(-k,k)$, which is a composition of reflection and scaling.